# How to find merged branch a commit came from?

Tags: git

I'm looking to find the originating branch of a commit. Not all the branches that contain this commit, but the branch that got merged into master that contained it.

I've seen some combination of 
`git rev-list <name_of_branch> | grep <sha>` & `git branch --contains <sha>` to get at this, but nothing direct.

My goal is that if there was a commit `1140bdf` that made it into `master` via branch `ta1234_foo`, that later I could assert that even after master was merged back into other branches.

We're using Github so if that's part of the solution it's ok—command-line is even better.

Answer (score 2):

This will show the history of merges that first incorporate a commit:

```
merges-introducing() {
    local introducing;
    if introducing=`git rev-parse $1`; then 
        shift
        git rev-list --ancestry-path --parents --reverse ^$introducing ${@-HEAD} \
        | awk '{seen[$1]=1} NR>1 && !seen[$2] {print $1}' \
        | xargs git show --oneline --no-patch
     fi
}
```

So for your case you'd do

```
merges-introducing 1140bdf master
```

to see the sequence of merges that introduced `1140bdf` to new branches on its way to the current master branch.

The idea's simple enough: `--ancestry-path --reverse` could be pronounced "descent path to", and any commit we see along that path that isn't descended from the interesting commit via its first parent can only be a merge incorporating the interesting commit into a branch for the first time.

Comment: Hello @jthill. 
That line looks good, but when I ran it, it seemed to show *all* master merges. Is a particular git version required?

Comment: You're right -- it wasn't eliminating all the uninteresting merges.  I think it prints only the interesting bits now.

Comment: A slight modification made this seem to work for me:
https://gist.github.com/jameswomack/9e19283bde4b9fce8d20

Comment: How does substituting `$introducing...$2` for `^$introducing ${@-HEAD}` help?  I can't see what effect you're after there.

Comment: If I use your script, it always says:
`fatal: master: no such path in the working tree.
Use 'git <command> -- <path>...' to specify paths that do not exist locally.`

Comment: On `fatal: unrecognized argument: --no-patch` had to change `--no-patch` with `-s`.